# How to use py dictionary to get names respect to ids in table?

Tags: python, django, dictionary

I have id of selected department from dropdown in my database , i want to bind name of that id to table , so it is possible using py dictionary .. how?

html

```
    <tbody id="myTable">

                {% for employee in employees %}

                <tr>
                    <td>{{ employee.employee_id}}</td>
                    <td>{{ employee.Name}}</td>
                    <td>{{ employee.designation}}</td>
                    <td>{{ employee.department_id}}</td>
                    <td>{{ employee.manager_id}}</td>
                    <td>{{ employee.location_id}}</td>
                    <td>

                        <a href="#editEmployeeModal" class="edit" data-toggle="modal"><i class="material-icons" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit">&#xE254;</i></a>
                        <a href="#deleteEmployeeModal" class="delete" data-toggle="modal"><i class="material-icons" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Delete">&#xE872;</i></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
          {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
```

Here "{{ employee.department_id}}" is binding my id from database , so how can i set id and names in dictionary so i will get name of that id?

models.py

```
  class Employee(models.Model):
       ACTIVE = 1
       INACTIVE = 2
       DELETED = 3

       STATUS_CHOICES = (
           (ACTIVE, 'active'),
           (INACTIVE, 'inactive'),
           (DELETED, 'deleted'),
       )
       USER_TYPE = (
           (1, 'user'),
           (2, 'hr'),
       )
       employee_id = models.CharField(max_length=15, primary_key=True)
       Name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)
       designation = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False)
       department_id = models.IntegerField(null=False)
       manager_id = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=False)
       date_of_joining = models.DateField(null=False)
       date_of_birth = models.DateField(null=False)
       location_id = models.IntegerField(null=False)
       email = models.EmailField(max_length=100, unique=True, null=False)
       contact_number = models.CharField(max_length=10 , unique=True, null=False)
       password = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)
       created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
       created_by = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)
       modified_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
       modified_by = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
       status = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=False, choices=STATUS_CHOICES)
       user_type = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=USER_TYPE)

       objects = UserManager()

       USERNAME_FIELD = "email"
       REQUIRED_FIELDS = ["Name"]

       is_anonymous = "FALSE"
       is_authenticated = "TRUE"

       thisdict = {
           "1": "Investment",
           "2": "Health",
           "3": "Motor",
           "4": "Term"
       }

       class Meta:
           managed = True
           db_table = "ht_employee"


   class Department(models.Model):
       ACTIVE = 1
       INACTIVE = 2
       DELETED = 3
       STATUS_CHOICES = (
           (ACTIVE, 'active'),
           (INACTIVE, 'inactive'),
           (DELETED, 'deleted'),
       )
       department_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
       department_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False)
       created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,  null=False)
       created_by = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)
       modified_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
       modified_by = models.CharField(max_length=100)
       status = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=False, choices=STATUS_CHOICES)

       objects = UserManager()

       class Meta:
           managed = True
           db_table = "ht_department"

       def __str__(self):
           return self.department_id
```

views.py

```
def managemp(request):

    employees = Employee.objects.all()
    department = Department.objects.all()
    location = Location.objects.all()
    return render(request, "manageemp.html", {'department': department, 'employees': employees, 'location': location})
```

Comment: add your views and models code.

Comment: department_id should really be  a foreign key